# LDAP authentication problem in ASP.NET Core for restricted users (logon workstations) using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard2_0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, .net-core, ldap, windows-server

I use Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard2_0 package to authenticate users from Active Directory and it works fine for most of users.

```
using (var cn = new LdapConnection())
{
    cn.Connect(ldapOptions.Host, ldapOptions.Port);
    var userDn = username.IndexOf('@') < 0 ? username + $"@{ldapOptions.Domain}" : username;
    cn.Bind(userDn, password);
    if (cn.Bound)
    {
        result.Result = AuthResult.Succeed;
        result.Message = "Login Successful using LDAP: {0}.";
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is when we need to authenticate users that are restricted to logon to only certain computers in our domain (Active Directory).

[image][image]

I added the computer that host my application (IIS & Win Server 2016) to the list but it still fails and restricted users cannot be authenticated yet.

How can I solve this issue? should I change my code? or Active Directory/IIS settings?

Comment: Do you have access to the domain controller logs? You could check to see which server the login is coming from and make sure it's the same computer you put in the list.

Comment: So, I have to check it with sys admin guys. Do you have any idea which log should I check?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. I just know that when I ask our admins to see where a login is coming from, they can tell me :)

Comment: As I checked, the users can logon interactively but they cannot login through the network (like Remote Desktop and the LDAP-enabled web application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LDAP authentication is generally sourced from the domain controller(s), so the domain controller(s) configured as the LDAP host need to be present in the logon workstations (userWorkstations) list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. We also have an exchange server that has OWA (outlook web access) enabled. I noticed that Our limited users could login into OWA without any problem while we only added mail (host name) in the logon workstations. Do you have any idea about how OWA do LDAP authentication?