# LDAP Authentication problem with users who have restricted workstations

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, ldap, directoryservices

I use System.DirectoryServices to authenticate users against active directory.
this is my code

```
     public bool Validate(string userId, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = LdapPath();
            string username = UserFullId(userId);
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry
                     (path, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            ds.FindOne();
            return true;
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
        {
            PublicVariables.SetLogError(ex, "authentication");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this code works fine with users who have not been restricted to a specific workstation. problem is that users who are restricted to a specefic workstation can not log in to my software.
the solution from this [LDAP authentication problem in ASP.NET Core for restricted users (logon workstations) using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard2_0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258020/ldap-authentication-problem-in-asp-net-core-for-restricted-users-logon-workstat/53617278) can not help me. because I don't have the permissions to change users restriction or grant logon permission to the active directory server.
any suggestion on how I can authenticate users regardless of their workstation ??

Comment: I doubt you would be able to authenticate without adding the domain controllers used for the LDAP authentication to the allowed workstation list -- the point of the userWorkstations restriction is to prevent the account from logging on from other sources. If you could authenticate from other clients, that would be a security vulnerability.

Comment: @LisaJ Thanks for your response. I thought that would be the case too. but according to my customer, there are other applications in my customer network that they are using AC  without adding LDAP server to their allowed workstations.

Comment: They may be doing a different type of authentication for those applications -- I usually use Kerberos when I've got a bunch of computers in a domain & users logging into that domain. It produces the "single sign on" experience where you're not logging into a dozen websites when you access them. Since the user is permitted to log onto their computer, they've got a Kerberos token. My server knows how to talk to AD using Kerberos, so is able to validate their token. Another option, if the customer has it set up, would be Microsoft ADFS setup (federated authentication).